How to use dockerized dbus for inter process communication on MacOS?
Maybe it is a bit of an exotic question, but somehow I don't get if it is possible to have dbus up and running in a docker container and to use it as a message middleware.
The actual use case looks like follow: There are 3 small services, which are running on an embedded device. These services are applications written in Go lang. All three services exchange messages between each other using dbus.
What I wanted to achieve is to create one single docker-compose file with these applications AND supporting services like dbus for the local development to be able to bootstrap all that stuff with just one single command.
So I wanted to start to dockerize the dbus and I have really no clue how to do that (and to be honest if it is possible at all). So I have three apps running on the MacOS and I want that they communicate via dbus, which runs in a Docker container.
Any ideas, recommendations, tutorials etc.?
Edited on 21 Sep 2024: I'v done some progress. I finally figured out a more or less correct Docker image and container setup, so the dbus daemon runs in container without any errors.
FROM ubuntu:24.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dbus
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/var/run/dbus/session
CMD ["sh", "-c", "dbus-daemon --session --address=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS --nofork"]

Container will be started using:
docker run -d --name dbus -v /tmp/dbus:/var/run/dbus dbus

So how can I test a connection? Internet says - use dbus-send. But the most funny part is - In order to run dbus-send on Mac I must start dbus on mac. So every time I execute dbus-send on the host, it goes to the "default" dbus - on my Mac...
So the actual question is - How can I test the dbus in container?

I think you have the right basic approach here: run the DBus daemon in its own containers, and then either configure the other containers to use its socket.  This is all Docker-related setup, and not really related to having a MacOS host.
(IME this is a somewhat unusual setup for anything other than Linux desktop applications.  In a Docker context I'm more used to seeing more generic messaging systems like RabbitMQ, or setups like gRPC or JSON-over-HTTP for point-to-point request-response calls.)
In Docker, it's probably somewhat easier to configure DBus to use a TCP socket.  The documentation notes that this has no security controls – requests are neither encrypted nor authorized – but if you don't make this socket available outside the Docker network then it minimizes the risk of this.  There doesn't appear to be a standard port number, so we can just pick one.  As with other servers in Docker we need to explicitly tell the server to listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address, see the --address option in dbus-daemon(1).
# dbus/Dockerfile
CMD ["dbus-daemon", "--nofork", "--address=tcp:host=dbus,bind=0.0.0.0,port=16979"]

I'll also assume you're using Docker Compose to launch multiple containers together.  Compose automatically handles several of the details of networking for you.  The DBus documentation points at godbus as its one known Go implementation, and that honors some standard environment variables to find the location of the DBus socket (see for example conn_unix.go).  You can pass these in your Compose file:
version: '3.8'
services:
  dbus:
    build: ./dbus
    # intentionally no ports:
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    environment:
      DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: tcp:host=dbus,port=16979


A harder setup is to use a Unix socket with a shared volume.  This is prone to permission issues.  The TCP-socket approach will work in multi-host container setups (Kubernetes, Docker Swarm, Amazon ECS) but you intrinsically cannot share a Unix socket in these environments.
The location of the system DBus socket is fairly well-known (in /var/run/dbus) but the session socket looks fairly variable, and it seems like a typical setup is to launch a DBus daemon as part of a desktop login startup, at which point it will set the socket location in an environment variable.  For this example I'll try to use the system bus; in the Dockerfile launch dbus-daemon --system and not --session.
You need to create a volume of some sort.  For a socket you need to make sure the volume is the directory containing the socket; don't try to mount the socket itself as a file.  Mount the same directory into every container.
version: '3.8'
services:
  dbus:
    build: ./dbus
    volumes:
      - dbus:/var/run/dbus
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    volumes:
      - dbus:/var/run/dbus
volumes:
  dbus: # empty

You will need to make sure all of the processes can read and write the socket.  It looks like a system DBus daemon may have some restrictions on what's possible and may not work for you; for a session daemon you might need to ensure that all of the containers have the same numeric user ID, which will both help find a /run/user/1000/bus path that embeds it and also will be necessary for Unix permissions on the socket.

The socket location is wherever you specify the socket location to be. Yes, if a session bus were launched by a desktop environment using the "dbus-launch" helper, then the latter would choose a variable socket address, but that is not required, as the actual dbus-daemon takes an explicit --address parameter (nor even typical anymore; e.g. most distributions have migrated towards a fixed "user bus" socket at /run/user/UID/bus).

That is to say, since this setup already falls very much outside the typical D-Bus use case, it is not required by any means to stick to one of the two built-in modes – it would be much more appropriate to completely ignore both "--system" and "--session" options and directly specify a custom config-file that doesn't have the unwanted restrictions and has the desired socket address.

Thank you for a very detailed response! In a meanwhile I updated the original question, because I achieved some progress, but I still have no clue, how can I connect to the dbus, which runs in container. And yes, you are 100% correct. This is not a usual setup. This is how I inherited a project and maybe in the future we will replace the dbus.

One more comment on TCP vs. a Unix socket: if you are using a Unix socket, and you are using a VM-based setup like Docker Desktop, you will not be able to access the socket from the host system; you have to use another container to test it out.  You could connect to a TCP socket via published port from anywhere that has appropriate network connectivity.

@DavidMaze Thank you for clarification. That helps a lot. Yes I am using Rancher Desktop. It looks like that we need a unix socket connection because we need security features of dbus. But does it also mean that if I will leave dbus directly on the host, services running in container will also not be able to access dbus on the host? So to say the other way round scenario?
